# How to implement this nested if(and statement?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to achieve a nested IF(AND statement. I'm comparing 1 columns number and seeing if it falls within ranges and above them, but I'm getting an error on it. Syntax structure looks right, I'm not sure why it's not registering. Any ideas?

`=IF(AND(M2>=O2,M2<=O2,"TSR MIN - TSR MID",IF(AND(M2>=P2,M2<=P2,"TSR MID - TSR MAX",IF(M2>Q2,"ABOVE TSR MAX",IF(M2>R2,"ABOVE C-LEVEL MAX"))))))`

Comment: how can M2 be both greater than AND less than the same number>

Comment: ahh, I see your point, wasn't paying attention. How can I just check to see if it falls between ranges spanning 4 columns?

Comment: please show a mockup of data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need "More than one value and less than the next":

```
=IF(AND(M2>=O2,M2<=P2),"TSR MIN - TSR MID",IF(AND(M2>P2,M2<=Q2),"TSR MID - TSR MAX",IF(M2>Q2,"ABOVE TSR MAX",IF(M2>R2,"ABOVE C-LEVEL MAX"))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was too focused on the cell references.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I was almost there, but the parentheses were a bit off. This makes a lot of sense in terms of separating the IF AND parts and leaving just the IFs towards the end